# Delphi wants package name as exe extension

Tags: delphi, package

My project is dynamic linked to PackageCommon.bpl. Distributed My project.exe wants PackageCommon.EXE on runtime but when i rename .bpl to .exe it is works fine. What is the reason?

[image]

I'm running Delphi XE3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you post te actual error message?

Comment: [error image](http://i50.tinypic.com/2rz9req.png)

Comment: Show us your project's runtime packages setting please.

Comment: *dynamically linked* means that you've got code calling `LoadPackage`. In addition to adding the runtime package settings, include the code where you're loading the package.